# What were the two scavenge maps removed from left4dead 2?

Tags: left-4-dead-2

When the game came out there were a couple of additional scavenge maps, which have since been removed (at least, from the PC version).

Does anyone have a link to what they were or remember which campaigns they were taken from and where abouts?

Comment: Do you have any references to maps having been removed?

Comment: Afraid not, I've googled a lot but can't find anything. I just remember when I started playing there were a couple of extra maps that were since removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done a bit of digging and reviewing cut content from Left 4 Dead 2. I looked at other sources, but this is the most comprehensive: [L4D2 Wikia: Cut Content](https://left4dead.fandom.com/wiki/Cut_Content).

I don't believe any Scavenge maps were cut before the release of the game.

You may be thinking of the The Coaster in Dark Carnival which was planned on being made a Survival map. From the wikia:

> Originally, The Coaster was supposed to be a survival level, but it was cut it in the final version because players would be able to stand on the wood that holds the track up, with the Infected unable to reach or attack them. The survival level can be accessed by the use of glitches or by using a [mod](http://www.l4dmaps.com/details.php?file=6826) from L4Dmaps.com.
>   Though the exploits have been fixed, the level still hasn't been returned.

From what I can research this is the only major cut map. All other maps received light-to-moderate transformations but no other level content was actually removed.

Comment: Interesting! I've given it a lot of thought and I reckon I may have mixed it up with the Lighthouse last stand mode. Perhaps because there are lots of gas cans on it. I remembered it as a scavenge map. Thanks for your rply.